# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (glumpy app)

Tags: anaconda, oserror, glumpy

Im getting this error while trying to run a code that uses glumpy library in python. Seems like the problem is when trying to run a command using "app". I'm using anaconda and python 3.6. I had hard time installing dlib and glumpy and I want to avoid installing them again on another environment. What can I do so i won't get this error? seems like the problem is in the package i guess?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/טל קרני/PycharmProjects/untitled/graphicstry.py", line 64, in <module>
    window = app.Window(color=(1, 1, 1, 1))
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\site-packages\glumpy\app\__init__.py", line 150, in __new__
    backend = use(name)
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\site-packages\glumpy\app\__init__.py", line 116, in use
    importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\site-packages\glumpy\app\window\backends\backend_glfw.py", line 82, in <module>
    from glumpy.ext import glfw
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\site-packages\glumpy\ext\glfw.py", line 63, in <module>
    _glfw = ctypes.CDLL(_glfw_file)
  File "C:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Answer (score 0):

This almost always means you're trying to load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process, or vice versa.  Are you running 64-bit Windows?  Did you install 64-bit Python?  Did you fetch the 64-bit person of glumpy?

Comment: My windows is 64 bit,  also when i run the python on the conda prompt it says this:                            Python 3.6.12 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep  9 2020, 00:29:25) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32          as i read im pretty sure it runs a 64 bit python

Comment: I tried to replace all the dll's i added to the files to 32-bit, and after that 64-bit, I tried running the program after both but still getting the error. Is there a way to check if I installed 32-bit or 64-bit glumpy?